# Kriging results are too localized, how can I increase the influence of each data point

Tags: r, variogram, kriging

I have a small dataset that looks like this...

```
a <-  WELL.ID    X      Y BENZENE
1    MW-02 268.8155 282.83 0.00150
2    IW-06 271.6961 377.01 0.00050
3    IW-07 251.0236 300.41 0.01040
4    IW-08 278.9238 300.37 0.03190
5    MW-10 281.4008 414.15 2.04000
6    MW-12 391.3973 449.40 0.01350
7    MW-13 309.5307 335.55 0.01940
8    MW-15 372.8967 370.04 0.01620
9    MW-17 250.0000 428.04 0.01900
10   MW-24 424.4025 295.69 0.00780
11   MW-28 419.3205 250.00 0.00100
12   MW-29 352.9197 277.27 0.00031
13   MW-31 309.3174 370.92 0.17900
```

I want to produce a raster map showing predicted values from an ordinary kriging interpolation and have been able to get this far...

```
require(geoR)
require(ggplot2)

a <- read.table("krigbenz_loc.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
dat <- as.geodata(a, coords.col = 2:3, data.col = 4, )
ggplot(a, aes(x= X, y= Y, colour="green", label=WELL.ID)) + geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label=WELL.ID),hjust=0, vjust=0)

##create grid to populate with krige values
x.range <- as.integer(range(a[,2]))
y.range <- as.integer(range(a[,3]))
x = seq(from=x.range[1], to=x.range[2], by=1)
y = seq(from=y.range[1], to=y.range[2], by=1)
length(x)
length(y)
xv <- rep(x,length(y))
yv <- rep(y, each=length(x))
in_mat <- as.matrix(cbind(xv, yv))
#plot(in_mat)

### variogram ###
## on geo-object
v1 <- variog(dat)
length(v1$n)
v1.summary <- cbind(c(1:11), v1$v, v1$n)
colnames(v1.summary) <- c("lag", "semi-variance", "# of pairs")
v1.summary
#plot(v1, type = "b", main = "Variogram: BENZENE at CRAIG BP")

### kriging predict for in_mat
## variance of benzene readings = sd^2
sd <- sd(a$BENZENE)
var = sd^2

## Covariance PHI of benzene in a spatial distribution using geoR
#used excel = ~ 0.29 for covariance of benzene values to themselves....

### try krig.conv
fitted_model <- variofit(vario=v1, ini.cov.pars=c(var, .29), cov.model='exp')
kctl <- krige.control(type.krige = "ok", trend.d = "cte", trend.l = "cte", obj.model = fitted_model,
                  cov.model=fitted_model$cov.model, cov.pars=fitted_model$cov.pars)
kcnv <- krige.conv(dat, locations = in_mat,  krige = kctl)

image(kcnv)
points(dat)
```

here my output is

[image: image(kcnv)]

[image: points(dat)]

My question is:

How do I set the parameters of the image or krig so that the radius of influence is increased?

I think I am trying to say the values of my interpolated raster are dropping to the (sill or nugget?) to quickly.... instead of one little island and a few points I should be seeing several oblate regions... like a groundwater plume should be....

as always, the help I receive here is greatly appreciated and I will be sure to post my completed solutions on all of the relevant questions I have asked regarding this problem.

Comment: The results reflect the data. (1) Your outlier in case 5 is really screwing things up. (2) You probably should be kriging the log concentrations. (3) Neither kriging nor any other interpolation method is likely to produce a reliable map based only on 13 values unless they are very slowly varying over local neighborhoods, which these clearly are not.

Comment: Wouldn't case 5 cause a large region to have similar values and the lower values join their own region? I am familiar with Kriging in ArcGIS and that is what I am looking for, I know the output currently is not accurate, this is a groundwater plume and the contamination is continuous from case 5 to the other cases,

Comment: Because you are using an automatic variogram estimator, you have given up all ability to inform the estimation with your understanding of how groundwater should behave. Accordingly, since the estimator sees extraordinary local variability, it fits a very short range. Much of this variability is due to the high outlier, but even if you were to remove that outlier (for variography only, of course) the range would still be pretty short. BTW, unless this is a homogeneous sandbox in a controlled environment, the benzene concentrations will not be as continuous as you think.

Comment: Funny you should say that, as it is as about as homogeneous as one can get (i have about 30 borehole lithology logs) except just this year about 600yds of contaminated soil was removed from the area just south of case 5, the open pit filled with rainwater and was not dewatered before backfilling! this created a hydrologic mound of 'clean' water that my potentiometric surfaces show a very nifty model of, as well as an interesting effect on contamination. in all, the ground is about as homogeneous as possible which is one thing that has gone right on this project - its been fun to say the least.

Comment: @whuber, can you show me a method that does not use an automatic estimator that will give me control over the model?

Comment: Doesn't `geoR` itself support interactive variography? If not, then the functionality must be in `geoRglm`. In your situation you have no reasonable expectation that benzene (or log benzene) will be adequately modeled by a stationary random field, which is one more reason ordinary kriging should do poorly. Consider some version of modeling the "drift" (overall trend) coupled with kriging the residuals. This could include universal kriging, residual kriging, a spatial GLM (supported by `geoRglm`), or even use of a simple advection-dispersion model followed by kriging its residuals.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this by modifying the variogram model: either decrease the nugget, or increase the range, or do both.

You didn't show a sample variogram + fitted model plot, so we can't tell from here whether the fitting went wrong, or the data simply exhibit nearly no spatial correlation.

Comment: I should be returning to this project in the near future, at which point I will resurrect these plots and see where we can take this thread. thanks for the response